# How to store multiple values in single cookie key

Tags: node.js

I want to store value entered in textbox in cookie like {values: value1, value2, value3} using angular node js. how should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the json object of values to String and then store it to cookies like-

```
$.cookie("formData", JSON.stringify($("#form").data()));
```

use form's id and get the data.

Comment: Thanks. I want to update each time when the user enter the value in textbox ,to the same cookie. how to do that?

Comment: Don't need to do anything special,just do the same as done for setting the cookie.
If cookie already present it will update it

Comment: I don't want to delete existing value. I want to add with existing value like an array.

Comment: ok, so in this case for the very first time get the value as an object, push to an array and convert to string  and store the result as told earlier

Comment: Now on new form submission, get the cookie value and also the current form data.
Now parse the cookie to object and push new object to the previos object/array and add again to cookie by converting to string

Comment: I am using anuglar 10. could you share the example code for that?

Comment: I have never used angular.
What you can do is find how to do it using medium. I you get stuck anywhere we can figure it together.

Comment: save(input: string) {
    var new_data = input;
    if (localStorage.getItem('data') == null) {
      localStorage.setItem('data', '[]');
    }
    var old_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
    if(!old_data.includes(new_data)){
    old_data.push(new_data);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(old_data));
    this.prevQueries = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')));
    // alert(this.prevQuery);
     
I tried like this. In local storage it works well. but cookies it doesn't work
  }